# renameTo always return false, eventhough I use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on Manifest (ANDROID)

Tags: android, rename

I'am looking for the answer why oldFileObj.renameto(newFileObj) always return false, eventhough i have use the Manifest WriteFile permission

please see the pic below..

[Code Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbumO.png)

[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaH2f.png)

My phone is Samsung Galaxy A5 Oreo

I have search all the problem that similar to mine, but still can't find the answer

the permission already granted

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32635704/115145

Comment: From android 23+ some permissions are not granted by declaring in the manifest file so you have to request the permission manually.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare for the answer, i will try it and see if it can solve the problem

Comment: Thank you @RohitSuthar for the answer..

Comment: Did you looked for a error in logs? Probably the log contains much more information about the problem, please, attach it. And, .renameTo it isn' a method of ANDROID, do you mean File class? Please, be more detailed.

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov sorry if my question is not clear, next time i will attach the Log. yes i mean Object.renameto() where the object is the instance from the File Class. Btw thanks for the answer, I will edit the title then